# How do I add UIImage to center of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uinavigationbar

My problem is that I have an image with `width = 44` and `height = 44`. This method didn't work properly.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_44.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

How do I add an `UIImage` to center of an `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: As background image (should anything be displayed on top of that) or as a plain image?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myUIImage];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleView];
```

Comment: Just be sure to set the opacity of your image view.

Comment: I've updated the code (added `topItem` call which has `titleView` property).

Answer (score 9):

Using Swift :

```
var titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "nameOfTheImage.ext"))
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Comment: This seems like is not available in AppDelegate? I get the error «Value of type 'UINavigationBar' has no member 'titleView'»