# Iphone Navigation bar insert png file

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbar

I have an iphone app, and i've inserted a png image instead of a text.
My issue is, well it's not even a issue but anyways, the image has some pixels in it. it looks a little scratched. with some transparency issues i guess.

Now my question is, can i do anything to improve the image's resolution within the code?
The image has 120px x 25px;
It seems like it makes the image a little bigger, i need something to keep it in the actual size.
Thanks.

This is the code i use:

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_bar.png"]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

Comment: see my so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206116/how-to-i-change-the-color-of-uinavigationbar/9206204#9206204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here maybe this code will solve all your navigational issues

```
self.navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.navigation.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigation] navigationBar];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation1.png"];  
[navBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigation.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
[self.window setRootViewController:self.navigation];
self.navigation.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Name";
```

Comment: Gill thank you, please, if this is not much to ask, i mean, based on my code, (because i'm a newbie and have no idea how to implement yours) , i mean, i get the image to appear, i just need to give that image a size, width and height, apparently, at the moment the image enlarges somehow, so how am i supposed to do that?

Comment: @Tao Oh you mean you want to simply add an image somewhere on the navigation bar ??

Comment: i mean, i just need to set a width and height to the image above, i've used, and for it to allow transparency...
please!

Comment: Yes, i've done that, it works, i just need to give the image a specific width and height.. also allow transparency!

Comment: See for giving the image a particular height or width you would have to create an UIImageView and then for reducing the transparency change its alpha ... Here check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506679/how-do-i-add-uiimage-to-center-of-uinavigationbar

Comment: UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]];    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 200, 80); for setting the frame

Comment: If you see the code i've pasted, i've already created the image, i just don't know where to set width and this alpha...

Comment: Thanks, now is more clearer, what is it going to do? i mean, resize this?